# javame - download and save mp3 file on

Tags: java, java-me

i have a javame project and im trying to create a method to download and save mp3 file to the phone. The method is shown below, unfortunately it keeps throwing an exception of java.lang.illegalargument exception.

```
    public void Download_KeyTest()
    {
        FileConnection file = null;
        OutputStream outStream = null;
        String resumeJSON = mPreferences.get("resume");
        JSONObject resumeObject;
        try {
            resumeObject = new JSONObject(resumeJSON);
            String key=resumeObject.get("code").toString();
            String inputStr=getTextField12().getString();
            if (inputStr.equals(key))
            {
            Enumeration roots = FileSystemRegistry.listRoots();
            String currentRoot = null;
            while (roots.hasMoreElements()) {
                currentRoot = (String) roots.nextElement();
                System.out.println(currentRoot);
                }
            HttpConnection hc = null;
            DataInputStream in = null;
            try {
            String url = d_url+resumeObject.getJSONObject("sObject").get("loc").toString();
            String sname = urlEncode(resumeObject.getJSONObject("sObject").getString("name").toString());
            hc = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
            int length = (int)hc.getLength();
            byte[] data = null;
            if (length != -1) {
                switchDisplayable(null,getWaitScreen1());
                data = new byte[length];
                in = new DataInputStream(hc.openInputStream());
                in.readFully(data);
                }
                else {
                // If content length is not given, read in chunks.
                switchDisplayable(null,getWaitScreen1());
                int chunkSize = 512;
                int index = 0;
                int readLength = 0;
                in = new DataInputStream(hc.openInputStream());
                data = new byte[chunkSize];
                do {
                    if (data.length < index + chunkSize) {
                    byte[] newData = new byte[index + chunkSize];
                    System.arraycopy(data, 0, newData, 0, data.length);
                    data = newData;
                    }
                    readLength = in.read(data, index, chunkSize);
                    index += readLength;
                } while (readLength == chunkSize);
            length = index;
            }
            getWaitScreen1().setText("Download Complete");
try {
            // Get path to photos folder.
            String dirMusic = System.getProperty("fileconn.dir.memorycard.music");
            if(dirMusic == null) {
                dirMusic=currentRoot;
                //throw new Exception("Unable get music folder name");
            }

            String fileName = dirMusic + sname +".mp3";
            // Open file
            file = (FileConnection)Connector.open(fileName, 
                    Connector.READ_WRITE);
            // If there is no file then create it
            if(file.exists() == false) {
                file.create();
            }
            // Write data received from camera while making snapshot to file
            outStream = file.openOutputStream();
            outStream.write(data);
            System.out.println(file.availableSize());
            //file.setHidden(false);

            getWaitScreen1().setText("Song saved to music folder.");

        } catch(IOException ioe) {
           Alert alertx = new Alert("IO error", ioe.toString(), null, AlertType.ERROR);
           alertx.setTimeout(Alert.FOREVER);
           switchDisplayable(alertx,getDownloadVerifyKeyForm());
        } catch(Exception exc) {
           Alert alertx = new Alert("Error", exc.toString()+exc.getMessage(), null, AlertType.ERROR);
           exc.printStackTrace();
           alertx.setTimeout(Alert.FOREVER);
           switchDisplayable(alertx,getDownloadVerifyKeyForm());
        } finally {
            // Try to close file
            try {
                if(outStream != null) {
                    outStream.close();
                }
                if(file != null) {
                    file.close();
                }
            } catch(Exception exc) {
                // Do nothing 
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        }            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        ex.printStackTrace();    
        }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
        ex.printStackTrace();    
        }
    }
```

here is the error i get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at javax.microedition.io.Connector.getProtocolInstance(), bci=28
    at javax.microedition.io.Connector.open(), bci=24
    at javax.microedition.io.Connector.open(), bci=3
 - spinapp.SpinApp.Download_KeyTest(SpinApp.java:703)
```

line 703 is this in the code

```
hc = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
```

Comment: I bet `resumeObject.getJSONObject("sObject").getString("name").toString()` does not result in something like `http://domain.tdl/path/file.mp3`. `getProtocolInstance()` fails, meaning that you do not provide a protocol (http://) or the protocol is unknown.

Comment: that returns the name for the file to be saved as. in my demo url = "http://127.0.0.1/relief/api/uploads/p17gnmso5duql0lnhevja15td5.mp3" and the file path i want it to save as ie fileName="root1/bogolako.mp3"

Comment: i know its downloading.... i think saving is the problem

Comment: **How** do you know it's downloading?  The line you say the exception is on (`Connector.open(url)`) is called before the download occurs, so either that's not the line where the exception is thrown, or the file is **not** actually downloading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Connector.open(String)` will throw `IllegalArgumentException` if the URL is invalid, so what we really need to see is the **exact** URL you're passing in.

It's a little bit hard to tell which URL that is, because of the way the Stack Overflow comment formatting works.  For future reference, if you want to paste in an exact URL into a comment, please format it as *code* with the single tick marks around it.  So, it's a little difficult to tell if your `url` variable includes the **protocol** prefix or not.

But, your full URL should probably be

```
http://127.0.0.1/relief/api/uploads/p17gnmso5duql0lnhevja15td5.mp3
```

Obviously, when testing URLs, it's usually *also* a good idea to paste the URL into a desktop browser, and make sure it works there, too.  This URL (host=127.0.0.1) says that you're running your server on the same machine as the simulator.

*(This brings up another point ... you say this is for the **phone** in your question, but the 127.0.0.1 server address is only going to work if you're running in the simulator)*

---

**Edit:** after looking over your comments again, I'm wondering if the exception isn't occurring on this line instead:

```
     file = (FileConnection)Connector.open(fileName, 
                Connector.READ_WRITE);
```

if `fileName` is equal to `root1/bogolako.mp3`, then you **are** missing the protocol for that call.  You should prefix `fileName` with `"file:///"`, assuming that `"/root1/"` is actually a valid absolute path on your simulator.

[See here for a J2ME file connection example](http://j2mesamples.blogspot.com/2009/02/file-connection-using-j2me-api-jsr-75.html)

Comment: @SirLojik, glad it was something simple after all :)